# Vagrant up issue

Tags: vagrant, puppet

We have a network that requires a proxy to go to the internet, I have a local Mac that we’re setting up for Drupal development and have `HTTP_PROXY` and `ALL_PROXY` set and everything works fine using bower, gem and librarian-puppet scripts from our development house to install these. I am now using a `Vagrantfile` they have created to setup a vagrant (VirtualBox) machine and hitting issues. I initially got issues early on in the script, but have installed `vagrant-proxyconf` and added `config.proxy.http`, https and no_proxy lines to the fine, which now gets a lot further before erroring with:

```
==> default: Info: Loading facts ==> default: Could not retrieve fact='nodejs_latest_version', resolution='': Connection refused - connect(2) ==> default: Could not retrieve fact='nodejs_stable_version', resolution='': Connection refused - connect(2) ==> default: Error: Invalid version string ''! at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-71ca71d9c718e523371ddd53fd147634/nodejs/manifests/install.pp:165 on node drupal.dev ==> default: Error: Invalid version string ''! at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-71ca71d9c718e523371ddd53fd147634/nodejs/manifests/install.pp:165 on node drupal.dev The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong.

The ‘SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.’ I see a few times in the script execution, but this is the first that stops the script running. If I connect the machine directly to an internet connection the script runs through successfully, but this isn’t a long term solution. I’m not sure if the issue is on the mac or the virtual box, or what file or setting I should be looking at. If anyone can help shed some light where the issue might be, or where I should be looking it would really be appreciated.
```

The debug output ends like this :

```
==> default: Info: Loading facts DEBUG ssh: stderr: Could not retrieve fact='nodejs_latest_version', resolution='': Connection refused - connect(2)

INFO interface: info: Could not retrieve fact='nodejs_latest_version', resolution='': Connection refused - connect(2) INFO interface: info: ==> default: Could not retrieve fact='nodejs_latest_version', resolution='': Connection refused - connect(2) ==> default: Could not retrieve fact='nodejs_latest_version', resolution='': Connection refused - connect(2) DEBUG ssh: stderr: Could not retrieve fact='nodejs_stable_version', resolution='': Connection refused - connect(2)

INFO interface: info: Could not retrieve fact='nodejs_stable_version', resolution='': Connection refused - connect(2) INFO interface: info: ==> default: Could not retrieve fact='nodejs_stable_version', resolution='': Connection refused - connect(2) ==> default: Could not retrieve fact='nodejs_stable_version', resolution='': Connection refused - connect(2) DEBUG ssh: stderr: Error: Invalid version string ''! at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-71ca71d9c718e523371ddd53fd147634/nodejs/manifests/install.pp:165 on node drupal.dev

INFO interface: info: Error: Invalid version string ''! at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-71ca71d9c718e523371ddd53fd147634/nodejs/manifests/install.pp:165 on node drupal.dev INFO interface: info: ==> default: Error: Invalid version string ''! at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-71ca71d9c718e523371ddd53fd147634/nodejs/manifests/install.pp:165 on node drupal.dev ==> default: Error: Invalid version string ''! at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-71ca71d9c718e523371ddd53fd147634/nodejs/manifests/install.pp:165 on node drupal.dev DEBUG ssh: stderr: Error: Invalid version string ''! at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-71ca71d9c718e523371ddd53fd147634/nodejs/manifests/install.pp:165 on node drupal.dev

INFO interface: info: Error: Invalid version string ''! at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-71ca71d9c718e523371ddd53fd147634/nodejs/manifests/install.pp:165 on node drupal.dev INFO interface: info: ==> default: Error: Invalid version string ''! at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-71ca71d9c718e523371ddd53fd147634/nodejs/manifests/install.pp:165 on node drupal.dev ==> default: Error: Invalid version string ''! at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-71ca71d9c718e523371ddd53fd147634/nodejs/manifests/install.pp:165 on node drupal.dev DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 1 ERROR warden: Error occurred: The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong. INFO warden: Beginning recovery process... INFO warden: Recovery complete. ERROR warden: Error occurred: The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong. INFO warden: Beginning recovery process... INFO warden: Calling recover: # INFO warden: Beginning recovery process... INFO warden: Calling recover: # INFO warden: Beginning recovery process... INFO warden: Recovery complete. INFO warden: Recovery complete. INFO warden: Recovery complete. INFO warden: Beginning recovery process... INFO warden: Recovery complete. ERROR warden: Error occurred: The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong. INFO warden: Beginning recovery process... INFO warden: Recovery complete. ERROR warden: Error occurred: The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong. INFO warden: Beginning recovery process... INFO warden: Calling recover: # INFO warden: Beginning recovery process... INFO warden: Recovery complete. INFO warden: Recovery complete. ERROR warden: Error occurred: The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong. INFO warden: Beginning recovery process... INFO warden: Recovery complete. ERROR warden: Error occurred: The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong. INFO warden: Beginning recovery process... INFO warden: Calling recover: # INFO warden: Beginning recovery process... INFO warden: Recovery complete. INFO warden: Recovery complete. INFO warden: Beginning recovery process... INFO warden: Recovery complete. INFO warden: Beginning recovery process... INFO warden: Recovery complete. INFO environment: Released process lock: machine-action-d3538fe6302dd66edcdb4c05283597a6 INFO environment: Running hook: environment_unload INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence... INFO runner: 2 hooks defined. INFO runner: Running action: environment_unload # ERROR vagrant: Vagrant experienced an error! Details: ERROR vagrant: # ERROR vagrant: The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong. ERROR vagrant: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:236:in execute'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:246:insudo' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/provisioners/puppet/provisioner/puppet.rb:251:in run_puppet_apply'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/provisioners/puppet/provisioner/puppet.rb:124:inprovision' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:133:in run_provisioner'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:incall' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in block in finalize_action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:incall' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:incall' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in block in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:inbusy' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:428:inhook' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:121:in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:121:inblock in call' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:103:in each'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:103:incall' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:incall' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:inblock in finalize_action' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:incall' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:inblock in run' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in busy'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:inrun' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:incall' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in block in finalize_action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:incall' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:incall' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in block in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:inbusy' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:incall' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:incall' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:incall' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:incall' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in block in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:inbusy' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:214:inaction_raw' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:191:in block in action'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:516:inlock' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:178:in call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:178:inaction' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/commands/provision/command.rb:30:in block in execute'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:226:inblock in with_target_vms' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:220:in each'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:220:inwith_target_vms' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/plugins/commands/provision/command.rb:29:in execute'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:inexecute' /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:301:in cli'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/bin/vagrant:174:in' INFO interface: error: The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong. The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong. INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError", "The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant\nassumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command\nshould be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what\nwent wrong."]
```

Comment: I had issues getting my environment set up behind a corporate PAC proxy and wrote my notes here: http://marcyoung.us/post/azure-github-proxy/ . You may be able to use some of that.

Comment: Are these behind an authenticated proxy?

Comment: Facing exactly same issue, any solution?

Comment: I gave up and got a mac, issues were too much too long and it ate away at my productivity. Sorry